# SVG.js requestAnimationFrame leak

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, requestanimationframe, devtools, svg.js

A little background: I'm currently working on a project that contains about 20-30 items with linear gradients which animate their stops continuously throughout the entire run time of the experience.

[gradient docs](http://documentup.com/wout/svg.js#gradient)
[animate docs](http://documentup.com/wout/svg.js#animating-elements)

As the site runs, the framerate drops continuously over time. Running the chrome dev tools timeline shows an insane amount of `requestAnimationFrame` calls from this library; more and more over time, thus the consistent drop in framerate. So much so that the chrome dev tools buffer fills up in a **few seconds**.

[image: screen shot 2015-01-29 at 12 49 40 am]

[Video](http://cl.ly/282q2d1X1O3p)

Here is my code:

```
var colors;
var fnAnimate;
var gradient;
var s1;
var s2;
var s3;
var stops;

colors = ['#EFFF22', '#D1FBFF', '#2759FF'];

gradient = draw.gradient('linear', function(stop) {
    s1 = stop.at(0, colors[0]);
    s2 = stop.at(0.4, colors[1]);
    s3 = stop.at(1, colors[2]);
    stops = [s1, s2, s3];
});

fnAnimate = function() {
    var color;
    var stop;

    color = _.sample(colors);
    stop = _.sample(stops);
    stop.animate().update({
        color: color
    });
};

setInterval(function() {
    fnAnimate();
}, 1000);
```

From my understanding of the documentation, each invocation of animate on an object should stop any preexisting animation on said object. [Checking here in the source](https://github.com/wout/svg.js/blob/master/src/fx.js#L434), that does seem to be the case. If you look closer at the [`stop` method](https://github.com/wout/svg.js/blob/master/src/fx.js#L368), it looks to clear an animation timeout and delete/reset some properties. It is **not** doing, however, one vital thing.

Looking through the [`fx.render` method](https://github.com/wout/svg.js/blob/master/src/fx.js#L165), on lines 189 and 192, we enter a `requestAnimationFrame` loop. This is good. **BUT** after looking around this entire library, [cancelAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.cancelAnimationFrame) is nowhere to be found. There's also an absence of a shim for it in the [`helpers.js` next to the `requestAnimationFrame` shim](https://github.com/wout/svg.js/blob/master/src/helpers.js#L125).

Essentially what is happening is that every time `animate` is called, a `requestAnimationFrame` loop is created, but never killed, nor a reference to it stored; thus creating zombie animation loops. This would explain the extreme amount of `requestAnimationFrame` calls I'm seeing in my dev tools timeline.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame might better be called `requestOneSingleAnimationFrame`.  'requestAnimationFrame(animateMe)' will request that the browser call animateMe **exactly one time--not repeatedly** like setInterval. And rAF will die after its one call to animateMe is achieved. That's why you see so many executions of rAF--because rAF must be called every time you want to request a new animation frame.  In practice, a new rAF is usually called within the animateMe function that was triggered by the last (now dead) rAF.

Comment: You are correct. However, if you look here https://github.com/wout/svg.js/blob/master/src/fx.js#L189, you'll see that the render function calls itself, thus creating a loop.

Comment: Sure, that's the normal pattern for using rAF---rAF calls a function that contains the next rAF call.

Comment: So if you take a look at the stop function https://github.com/wout/svg.js/blob/master/src/fx.js#L368, there's nothing that cancels that loop.

Comment: I can't really review the entire svgjs library with you, but the stop() function calls `this.animate(0)` which sets the variable `d` to zero which eventually sets `start` equal to `finish` which terminates the animation. BTW, it's not unusual to let an rAF loop run forever. As long as the loop does no work it's relatively harmless.

Comment: closed with https://github.com/wout/svg.js/commit/2fc54cb89bef303efa9be3dfcd26ff10921deb04